# Analysis of solution of $y'=\sin(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $y'=\sin(y)$ with $y(0)=y_0$.

I should argue why y is monotone.

1. For $y_0=z*\pi/2$, z being whole numbers, we have $y(t)$ is constant
2. For $y_0=((\pi/2)(z-1), (\pi/2)z)$ we have $y(t)=((\pi/2)(z-1),(\pi/2)z)$

$\sin(y)$ is always positive or negative so y is monotone.

I have the argumentation but I don't understand the train of thought there.

For 1. how come y is constant based on the information of the initial condition. The same thing I don't understand about 2.

There is obviously something I don't understand but I am not able to figure it out apparently.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Think about the existence and ***uniqueness*** of solutions theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y$ is not monotonic (which also implies $y$ is non-constant).

Since $y$ is not monotonic, the value of $y'$ needs to change from positive to negative or from negative to positive at some point, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is at least one point $x_*$ such that $y'(x_*)=0.$ But, since $y'(x_*)=\sin(y(x_*))$, then $\sin(y(x_*))=0 \implies y(x_*)=n\pi$ and $y(x)=n\pi$ $\forall x>x_*.$ However, a similar argument shows $y(x)=n\pi$ $\forall x<x_*$ as well, hence a contradiction, hence $y$ must be monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of the given equation 
$\frac{dy}{sin y}=dx$
Gives,$\ln|tan\frac{y}{2}|=x+\ln |tan\frac{y_0}{2}|$
$$\implies |tan\frac{y}{2}|=e^x|tan\frac{y_0}{2}|$$

Comment: OP wants something else.